# linear 1st order differential help with exponentaled t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve
$x'+2x=5e^{3t}$

I've tried 
$x'+2x = 0$ but then I no longer have a differential

I've tried 
$x'+2x=5e^{3t}$

$\frac{x'+2x}{5e^3t}$
Which ended up being $x' = 0$

I have no idea how to try and get the 3t to a usable thing. I've thought about using ln but

$ln|x+2x|=ln|5|*3t$

doesn't look right.

Comment: First try to find an integrating factor for this DE.

Comment: Haven't covered integrating factors yet.

Comment: This is a linear 1st-order DE, so have you covered how to solve those?

Comment: we have covered solving linear 1st order DE. I understand that that is what this is. I'm trying to isolate the t. My latest attempt is the following.

x'+2x=5e^(3t)

ln|x+2x|=ln|5|*3t

ln|x'+2x|/3t = ln|5|

ln|x'+2x|/3t = 0

and stuck at this point. I could

x'+2x/ln|3t| = 0

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-LinearDiffEqns_Stu.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. From $x'=-2x$ is follows $\frac{1}{x}x'=-2$ Now integrating gives $ln|x|=-2t+C$ which becomes $x=Ae^{-2t}$ with A some constant. This is the most simple way in my view to get the first part right. Now have you covered how to get the particular solution that covers $5e^{3t}$?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't understand how to get to that part with the t being an exponential.

Comment: Considering the question, your notes must have something of how to get that $5e^{3t}$ part right. Would you give it a try and share with us?